# Insert UITableViewController into Other UIView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I've got a UITableViewController that inserts custom UITableViewCells into a UITableView.  Is there a way that I can put this UITableController/View combo into different views?  I've got the behavior of the UITableView acting the way I want, I just want to use that UITableView in different UIViews (say a UIView with a UILabel above the UITableView and one with a UILabel below the UITableView).

I know I can make a UIViewController that has an embedded UITableView in it and have the UIViewController act as the UITableView's delegate, but then I would have code reuse (the UITableViewController logic would be in multiple UIViewControllers). Or am I looking at this problem the wrong way?

I want to somehow reuse the functionality of my UITableView in different UIViews.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874135/error-when-add-uitableviewcontroller-as-subview-in-uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can, simply instantiate (or get a reference to) the UITableViewController inside the UIViewController and call something like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:tableViewController.tableView];
```

Comment: Thanks! The secret was the `tableViewController.tableView`.  I ended up doing this in IB, so my call was `[self.tableViewController setTableViewController:[self tableView]]`

Comment: don't forget thought you typically need addChildViewController as well! ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874135/error-when-add-uitableviewcontroller-as-subview-in-uiviewcontroller