# How can I clone a UITableView from one controller to another so it stays in synch?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364254/insert-uitableviewcontroller-into-other-uiview) in SO; it doesn't exactly answer my question, which is: is there a way to *clone* a UITableView from one controller to another while using Storyboards and maintain synchronization?

Comment: I've not used Storyboards, so I can't be sure, but presumably you set the table view's data source and delegate somewhere? If so, the table views should presumably stay in sync if you use the same instance for these in all cases.

Comment: Can't connect them in IB - different controllers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone them in the sense that their initial property values remain the same, like position, layout etc. For this, just copy the UITableView from storyboard, go to destination view controller and paste it there.

If you share same UITableView object between two view controllers, it is still possible, but you must estimate how much work you would have to do yourself. When a view controller solely handles a table view, much of the work is done under the hood and table is handed over to you. In case of your UITableView shared between two view controllers, you would have to play with it quite carefully. You need to take care of entire life cycle of the view - see the usual methods like `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear` and so on. How would you take care of them when your view exists in two scenes? Maybe you would be inventing a unique design pattern - if at all you find the most optimistic and programmatically correct way to accomplish it.

With storyboards, you cannot achieve cloning up to the level wherein data changes will reflect seamlessly between the two. Storyboard is, as the name suggest, just a board, where you can draw things to know how would they look initially, before your code takes over.

In order to achieve what you want, you have to create a shared model that updates two table views through proper delegate methods. Most likely such a model (NSArray, or any such collections as per your requirement) can reside inside a shared class (app delegate isn't a wrong choice), from where both your view controllers can refer to it. That is neat practice, it not only is right from programming perspective but also extensible and helpful to anyone who deals with the code any time.

For details about how to update UI from your model, there is nothing better than [starting from scratch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html), going through the books I mean.

Comment: Not to mention, you can also make both your UITableViewControllers aware of any changes to your shared model, using observer pattern. It is very easy to implement, read Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-CHDDBJEJ

Answer (score 0):

I am *not aware of such possibilities*.

I would **pass the tableview source object amongst different controllers** and let the view controller handle their own table view.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to use a framework such as the freely available Sensible TableView, then use the same model for both table views. This should be really straight forward.